# Profiling the OCaml compiler

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, profiling, ocaml

Background information (you do not need to repeat these steps to answer the question, this just gives some background):

I am trying to compile [a rather large set of generated modules](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d22wxiti0134hwt/generated.sources.tar.bz2?dl=0). These files are the output of a prototype Modelica to OCaml compiler and reflect the Modelica class structure of the Modelica Standard Library.

The main feature is the use of polymorphic, open recursion: Every method takes a `this` argument which contains the final superclass hierarchy. So for instance the model:

```
model A type T = Real type S = T end A;
```

is translated into

```
let m_A = object
            method m_T this = m_Modelica_Real 
            method m_S this = this#m_T this 
          end
```

and has to be closed before usage:

```
let _ = m_A#m_T m_A
```

This *seems* to postpone a lot of typechecking until the superclass hierarchy is actually fixed, which in turn makes it impossible to compile the final linkage module (try `ocamlbuild Linkage.cmo` after editing the comments in the corresponding file to see what I mean).

Unfortunately, since the code base is rather large and uses a lot of objects, the type-structure might not be the root cause after all, it might as well be some optimization or a flaw in the code-generation (although I strongly suspect the typechecker). So my question is: Is there any way to profile the ocaml compiler in a way that signals when a certain phase (typechecking, intermediate code generation, optimization) is over and how long it took? Any further insights into my particular use case are also welcome.

Comment: As a side note, it is considered bad practice in OCaml to start your filename with an uppercase letter. `Linkage.cmo` would be better as `linkage.cmo`.

Comment: I can suggest you "ocp-memprof" if you want to profile the ocaml compiler. The main page of ocp-memprof : http://memprof.typerex.org/

Answer (score 4):

As of right now, there isn't.

You can do it yourself though, the compiler source are [open](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/) and you can get those and modify them to fit your needs.

Depending on whether you use `ocamlc` or `ocamlopt`, you'll need to modify either `driver/compile.ml` or `driver/optcompile.ml` to add timers to the compilation process.

Fortunately, this already has been done for you [here](https://github.com/chambart/ocaml-1/tree/comparison_branch). Just compile with the option `-dtimings` or environment variable `OCAMLPARAM=timings=1,_`.

Even more easily, you can download the opam Flambda switch:

```
opam switch install 4.03.0+pr132
ocamlopt -dtimings myfile.ml
```

Note: Flambda itself changes the compilation time (most what happens after typing) and its integration into the OCaml compiler is not confirmed yet.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml compiler is an ordinary OCaml program in that regard. I would use [poorman's profiler](http://poormansprofiler.org/) for a quick inspection, using e.g. [pmp](https://github.com/ygrek/scraps/blob/master/pmp) script.